# Partial derivative of a function defined in a rectangular area

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I noticed in a book that it considers a function $u(x,y)$ in the rectangular area : $x\in (0, 1)$ ,$y\in (0, 1]$, and takes there the $\partial_y$. As I am used to only to take partial derivatives in open sets,  I would appreciate a clarification of the value of $\partial_y(x,  1)$. Is it $$\partial_y{u(x,  1)}=\lim_{t\to 1^{-}}\frac{u(x, t) -u(x, 1)}{t-1}$$  or something else? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your definition of partial derivative with respect to $y$ at $(x,1)$

$$ \partial_y{u(x,  1)}=\lim_{t\to 1^{-}}\frac{u(x, t) -u(x, 1)}{t-1}$$

is correct. Of course it is one sided because we do not have $y>1$ as part of the domain.